# How to make text preview with php, given text stored as markdown

Tags: php, markdown, preview

The text might have code blocks, so cutting the part and then processing is not a solution.
I was thinking about special syntax for splitting the text into preview and main part for markdown, but did not find one.

**Upd** So, to make it clear: I have texts in database, stored as markdown.
Some of texts might have quotations or code blocks. I want to generate preview texts, to show in some list page. This preview must be limited by length, ex 200 symbols max. If I'd just do `Markdown::process(substr($text, 0, 200))` I'll have errors if code block started before symbol #200 and ends after it. So I would like to know how other people solved similar problems.
Please, do not propose javascript solutions, I need this to be done on back-end, and do not want to use nodejs just for this task.

Comment: Please share some code, and be (a lot) more accurate as to what you'd like to achieve and what hasn't worked so far.

Comment: 5s Google: https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js

Comment: @Jeto, I added more details. Thanks for interest and assistance

Comment: @catcon, I can't see how this can solve the problem.

Comment: What if you process all your text before getting a substring?

Comment: @iArcadia, result of process is html, doing `substr` on html is even worse, it might create nonclosed tags.

Comment: @13DaGGeR But you could parse your result and check for non closed tags, then append corresponding closed ones to your result. (Just an idea, I don't know if it's the best solution)

Comment: @iArcadia, actually, it will be easier to close non-closed code tags in clipped source markdown

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with solution:

1. When editing text, add an `<hr>` tag, ex. `\n---\n` in place you think will be nice to split text
2. When showing preview, get text until the first `<hr>`, process it
3. When showing full text, remove first `<hr>`

If there are no `<hr>`-s in text, split as a plain text.

Not ideal solution, will update if find out the better one.